# windows 7 screen saver does not turn on

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, flash, power-management

I'm running win7 on a desktop. Power scheme is always on. 
Only the monitor is supposed to turn off.

Sometimes it will turn off, other times it won't.

Usually when it does not, what I have on screen is 
chrome browser with a flash app.

Any ideas why monitor off does not kick in?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with Chrome and the way it takes focus in Windows.  The problem is detailed by many people here:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9853

The workaround is to set your screen saver to 1 minute less than the power off time for the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because the Flash app is running.

Try it with Chrome but no Flash app and another browser with a Flash app.

Comment: Exactly my thought. Big question is how to make power management
work properly, regardless on what's on the display.

Comment: Well if you do my tests you'll know for certain, and knowing is half way to solving.